# Problem with files instanceof File, file is undefined

Tags: typescript, file

This is part of my code, I have problem with if statement, I uploaded file in my application and when it comes to the if statement file is undefined. I think problem is with importing.

I imported this

```
import csv from 'csv-parser';
import fs from 'fs';
```

Do you have any suggestion

```
let file;
if (files instanceof File) {
    file = files;
} else if (Array.isArray(files) && files.length > 0) {
    file = files[0];
}
```

I also tried this

```
const file = files.file;
if (file) {
  this.readFile(file.path)
  .then((results: FileInputDTO[]) => inputs = results)
  .then(() => { })
}
```

but in this case I have problem with `file.path` (`Property 'path' does not exist on type 'File | File[]'.`)

Note: this is code worked fine, but after raising some versions, error on `file.path` is appeared.

[Link for picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7jjD.png)

Comment: What is `File`? Node uses only filepaths and streams iirc

Comment: `let file = Array.isArray(files) ? files[0] : files;`

Comment: @Dimava please look at picture from above (Link for picture). Same issue

Comment: We don't speak "picture" here. [Edit] your question to show the code as it is when you receive the error, in a [mre]. It appears as though you may be mixing your backend and frontend logic here; the File API is specific to browsers and the frontend, whereas `fs` and filesystem-level access is generally backend-specific.